# Doing english to pig-latin with python2, converting words with alphabets to pig-latin done, how to modify it to add numbers and special characters

Tags: python-2.x

Converting English and Special Characters to Pig Latin Script (as in https://lingojam.com/PigLatinTranslator ) using Python 2.

Done English to Pig Latin.  Rest Pending.

Here the code

```
import re

def split_word(sentence):
    temp=sentence       
    while temp[0] not in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']:
            temp = temp[1:]
    else:
            t=temp

    s=re.split(r'[a e i o u A E I O U]', sentence)
    while len(s) > 1 : 
        s.pop()
        j_sentence= ''.join(s)
    print "\nCoressponding Pig-Latin translation :",t+j_sentence+"ay"+" "
    return t+j_sentence+"ay"+" "

try:
    while (True):
        s=""
        sentence=raw_input("\nEnter text to split or ctrl + D to exit : ").split(" ")
        if sentence==['']: 
            print "\nPlease enter a sentence !!" 
        else:   
            for i in sentence: 
                s+=split_word(i)
except EOFError:
    print "\n\nExited Sucessfully!!!"
    pass    
print s
```

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: there are errors when adding numbers and special character input, I want to know how this code can be modified to add numbers and special characters and obtain the result as in https://lingojam.com/PigLatinTranslator